# D3: Create bar for only one string in my json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to create bar graph with just one of the strings in my json. Here is an example of a json:

```
var fruits = [{
    kind: "grape",
    color: "red",
    quantity: 12,
    tasty: true
}, {
    kind: "kiwi",
    color: "brown",
    quantity: 98,
    tasty: true
}, {
    kind: "banana",
    color: "yellow",
    quantity: 0,
    tasty: true
}];
```

Now, I only want to create a single bar in my graph for quantity.

Is this possible or should I just reformat my data?

The length of that bar should be the mean of all the values. Here is my code so far:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("p")
           .data(fruits)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", 0)
           .attr("y", 0)
           .attr("width", 20)
           .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                return d3.mean(fruits, function(d) {return d.quantity * 20})
           });
```

That sort of gives me "one" bar with the right length. But actually it's three bars stacked on top of eachother since x = 0 for all rects.

Comment: You will need to pre-process your data.

Comment: Do you really just want to draw one bar or is it more like hiding the other bars? Second option would enable you to show the others again on some event.

Comment: Eventually I will want to use the other data as well, but I'd still be showing only the one bar. For example, I want users to be able to filter the data in way that they can see the quantity of grapes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a lot simpeler than I thought. I was to much focussed on the using the data to create svg rects.

I solved it by simply appending a single rectangle to the SVG.

```
d3.select("svg").append("rect")
       .attr("x", 0)
       .attr("y", 0)
       .attr("width", 20)
       .attr("height", function(d, i) {
            return d3.mean(fruits, function(d) {return d.quantity * 20})
       });
```

Excuse me if I've wasted your time in any way.